# C# NEST Elasticsearch - How to get all Increments?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, couchbase, nest

I have an issue that I want to consult with you - I want to pull out all my increments (not simple objects - increments), for example, if I do this on Couchbase:

```
client.ExecuteIncrement(key, defaultValue, delta, expirationTime.Value));
```

I want to be able to pull it from Elasticsearch like this:

```
            ISearchResponse<object> result = _mainManager.Client.Search<object>(q => q
                .Type() // ??
                .From(0)
                .Size(10));
```

Is there anyone who did that kind of thing? thanks!

UPDATE:

I usually I do mapping by a field type, that I declare in the object, like this:

```
            result = indexClient.Map<CBTemplate<JMEmbedDynamicAPILog>>(m => m.Type("EmbedAPILog")
                .MapFromAttributes()
                .TimestampField(t => t
                    .Enabled()
                    .Path(o => o.doc.APICreationDateTime)
                )
                .Properties(pprops => pprops
                    .Object<JMEmbedDynamicAPILog>(no => no
                        .Name(n => n.doc)
                        .MapFromAttributes()
                        .Properties(props2 => props2
                            .String(s => s
                                .Name(n2 => n2.APIErrorDescription)
                                .Index(FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)
                                .Analyzer("standard")
                            )
                        ))
                    )
                );
```

But since Increment is not an object, it doesn't have a Type field..

Comment: Can you provide more detail please? For example, it's not clear what incrementing a counter in Couchbase has to do with Elasticsearch. What do the indices/types/mappings look like in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Sure, updated my question.

Comment: It's still not clear how incrementing a counter in Couchbase relates to the Elasticsearch query. How do the two relate? Are you sync'ing data from Couchbase into Elasticsearch in some way?